# gitのpullで追加分だけmergeしたい

Tags: git

git初心者です。

gitのpullで削除はmergeさせず、追加だけmergeさせたいです。

まずやったことを順を追って説明します。
1.masterブランチを作成する。
2.masterブランチでsample1.txtを作成する。
3.masterブランチからtestブランチを作成する。
4.testブランチでsample1.txtを消して、sample2.txtを作成する。
5.masterブランチにcheckoutする。
6.masterブランチにtestブランチをmergeする。

↑ 6.の時にsample1.txtを残したままsample2.txtをmasterにpullしたいです。

何か方法はあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

前提として`git pull`は裏で`fetch + merge`を行うので、自動で変更をmergeされて困る場合は
まず`git fetch`で内容を確認してからmergeを行う必要があります。

---

他のブランチの変更(コミット)のうち、一部のファイルのみ取り込みたい場合には`git checkout`でブランチ名と対象のファイル名を指定すればよいみたいです。

```
git checkout <ブランチ名> -- <ファイル名>
```

今回の場合であればmasterブランチ上で以下のコマンドを実行すれば、testブランチのsample2.txtのみをチェックアウトすることができるはずです。

```
git checkout test -- sample2.txt
```

参考：
[Git 1ファイルだけ別のブランチから持ってくる - Qiita](https://qiita.com/oret/items/b646fcada9d89ed308c4)

Answer (score 3):

見た人を混乱させるだけなので**絶対に行うべきではない**と考えますが、やろうと思えば所望のmerge操作は行えます。

> 6.masterブランチにtestブランチをmergeする。

で、[`--no-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---no-commit)オプションを付ければコミット直前で停止できます。

```
git merge --no-ff --no-commit test
```

ので、このタイミングで `sample1.txt` の削除操作を取り消せば所望のmerge動作になります。

```
git reset -- sample1.txt
git merge --continue
```

(`push`/`pull` が手順1-6のどこで関わってくるのか不明確だったので`master`, `test`ブランチともローカルブランチとして書いていますが、`pull` にも[同じオプションがあり](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---no-commit)、考え方は同じです。)

---

行おうとしていることがそもそも"マージ"ではないので、`merge`コマンド以外で解決するのが妥当な考え方かと思います。

あるいは、`test`ブランチの改変が許されるのであれば、

> 4.testブランチでsample1.txtを消して、sample2.txtを作成する。

のコミットを

1. `sample2.txt` を作成するコミット
2. `sample1.txt` を消すコミット

の2つに分け、1つめのコミットだけを`master`にマージすることでも対応できるかと思います。