# リモートリポジトリから特定のコミットだけをローカルに反映したい

Tags: git

Visual Studio Community2019及びバージョン管理初心者です。
ある活動でバージョン管理が必要になったため、環境を構築し始めています。
pullについてわからないことがあるため、ご教示ください。
そしてpullについて私が誤解しているようでしたら、それもご指摘お願いします。

リモートリポジトリの特定のcommitのみ、ローカルリポジトリに反映させることができますか？

例えば、共同開発者が1つのリモートリポジトリの中にあるAとBという2つのファイルにそれぞれcommitをして変更を加えたとします。そして、私は自分のローカルリポジトリのAファイルのみ、リモートリポジトリと同期させたい(共同開発者のcommitを自分のローカルリポジトリのAに反映させたい)とします。その時どのような操作を行えば実現できますか。

自分のローカルリポジトリのBファイルには共同開発者のcommitを反映させたくありません。
そしてこの操作をVisual Studio Community上で行いたいです。

現在、リモートリポジトリにはAzure DevOpsを、ローカルリポジトリにはGit、そしてVisual Studio Community 2019を用いて環境構築をしています。リモートリポジトリは共同開発者と共有しています。

ご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えてください。
どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 複数のファイルの変更をまとめたものがcommitであり、リモートからcommitを取り込む行為がpullです。「特定のファイルのみpull」は原理上あり得ず、何を実現したいのかが伝わりません。この際、用語は気にせず、具体的にやりたいことを説明してください。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。質問内容を編集いたしました。

Comment: Aをpull、commit、pushは通常の操作であり重要なのはBの方です。リモートで更新されたBを取得したくないのか、それともローカルで更新したBをコミットしたくないのか、どちらでしょうか？

Comment: リモートで更新されたBを取得したくありません。自分のローカルにあるBはそのままにしたいです。

Comment: 更新された質問文はリモートからローカルに取り込む点しか言及されていませんでした。確認ですが、ご自身がローカルで変更したAをリモートリポジトリや共同開発者に反映不要ですか？

Comment: はい、自分のローカルで変更したAは、リモートリポジトリには反映不要です。

Answer (score 1):

git におけるコミットとは、リポジトリ (管理フォルダ配下) 全体の状態を保存したものになります。

特定コミットの中から個別のファイルの変更のみ取り出すことも可能ではありますが、"他人のコミットを反映させたくない" ならGitを使った共同編集のメリットが薄いように感じます。

作業用のブランチを切って、そこに必要なコミット(または特定のファイルのみ)を取り込む、というやり方にありそうです。

コミットから指定のファイルの変更のみ取り出すには、以下の形式でコミットIDとファイルのパスを指定します。

```
$ git checkout <commitID> <path_to_file>
```

---

**追記**
過去に類似質問への [回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/55874) でも記載しましたが、`git pull` は裏で `fetch + merge` を行うので、取り込みたくないものが含まれているなら `git pull` は使うべきではありません。

Comment: コミットから指定のファイルの変更のみ取り出すのは、Visual Studio Community上の操作ではできないのですか？やはりgit bashなどを使用しないと指定した変更のみを取り出すことはできないのでしょうか。

Comment: この方法って、取り出した後、commit & pushできますっけ？ 履歴がつながるか気になりました。

Comment: @sayuri 個別に checkout した分は新たな差分扱いになるので、add, commit すること自体は可能です。

Answer (score 1):

表題の

> リモートリポジトリから特定のコミットだけをローカルに反映したい

と、文中の

> Aファイルのみ、リモートリポジトリと同期させたい

のどちらを実際にやりたいのかにもよりますが、まず前者は[`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)で可能です。

```
git fetch
```

でremote-trackng branchが最新化されますので、そこから取り込みたいcommitのハッシュ値を確認し、

```
git cherry-pick <取り込みたいcommitのハッシュ値>
```

で取り込めます。

後者の場合は、

```
git fetch
```

を行いremote-tracking branchを最新化した後、

```
git checkout <remote-tracking branch名> -- <Aファイル>
```

で可能です。
最近のバージョン([2.23](https://mag.osdn.jp/19/08/19/183000)以降)だと[`restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)コマンドでも同じことができます:

```
git restore --source <remote-tracking branch名> --staged --worktree -- <Aファイル>
```

また、

> 自分のローカルにあるBはそのままにしたいです。

ということであれば、Aファイルだけ最新状態を取り込む、のではなく、リモートブランチの変更を全て取り込んだ上でBファイルだけ古い状態(=リモートの変更を取り込む前のローカルブランチの最新状態)に戻す、という考え方もあるかと思います。